# background color not applying when convert html to pdf table in c# using htmlparser

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation, html-parsing, itext

I need to convert some html strings to generate pdf file, but it doesn't apply any style(Inline style). If using **pdtable** no problem, but in my case I can't able to used **pdftable** also.

I tried the following code, it generate the pdf successfully but no styles are there

My Code is

```
string resHtml = "<table style='background:red" width='100%' border='1' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'><tr><td align='center'>TD2</td><td align='center'>TD1</td></tr>   <tr><td align='center'>TD2</td><td align='center'>TD1</td></tr>     </table><table><tr border='0'><td style='text-align: center;font-size:10px;color:#99999B;'>This is Computer genarated pay slip does not require any signatures</td></tr></table>"; 

iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.StyleSheet styles = new iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.StyleSheet();

styles.LoadTagStyle("table", "background", "red"); //I found this in stackoverflow but no use

StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(resHtml);

Document Doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 50f, 20f);
HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(Doc);
PdfWriter.GetInstance(Doc, Response.OutputStream);
Doc.Open();
htmlparser.Open();
htmlparser.Parse(stringReader);
htmlparser.SetStyleSheet(styles);
htmlparser.Close();

Doc.Close();
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + filename + ".pdf");
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Write(Doc);
Response.End();
```

Comment: `HtmlWorker` has long since been declared obsolete. Have you tried to reproduce the issue with `XmlWorker`?

Comment: I am curious: is this new code? Or is this very old code under maintenance? If it is new code, then I would like to know why people don't use `XMLWorker` and where they got the idea to use `HTMLWorker`. Definitely not from the examples on http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples. Maybe from some outdated tutorial that we have no knowledge of? If you could give me the website where you found that, maybe the author of the tutorial can be asked to update his tutorial.

Comment: Yes, this is very old project, thanks for your suggestion ill try with xmlworker.